# How to secure Rest API using Spring Boot OAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I want to create a sample **Spring Boot application with OAuth2** integration which is having a **CustomTokenEnhancer** and it should expose /oauth/token URL to client without access token but all the other URL with can be queried only if they have a valid access token.
I am able to setup the CustomTokenEnhancer by which I am able to send the additional stuff when request comes for /oauth/token.

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrzUd.png) 
**Application.java** - Spring Boot Application class
**AuthorizationServerConfiguration.java** - Authorization Server 
**ResourceServer.java** - Resource Server
**OAuth2SecurityConfiguration.java** - extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and defines in memory user
**CustomTokenEnhancer.java** - Send additional stuff with access token like cookies

In OAuth2SecurityConfiguration.java , I am configuring the 3 URLs , /oauth/token can be queried by anyone which have the clientId and secret and once you have the access token. Client should be able to query the all the other URLs in my case `/test` and `/inventory/sku/{skuID}`

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll().antMatchers("/inventory/**","/test").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN");

}
```

But I am getting forbidden 401 when I am querying /test or /inventory/sku/1100.

I need help in making two URL /test and /inventory/sku/1100 available only with access token and /oauth/token without access token.

**OAuth2SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.ClientDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.ApprovalStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenApprovalStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public OAuth2SecurityConfiguration() {
        System.out.println("OAuth2SecurityConfiguration()");
    }

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("OAuth2SecurityConfiguration globalUserDetails() ,invoke BJSCustomAuthentication");

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication() // authenticationProvider(new
                                        // BJsCustomAuthentication());
                .withUser("bill").password("abc123").roles("ADMIN").and().withUser("bob").password("abc123")
                .roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll().antMatchers("/inventory/**","/test").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN");
        //http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            //  .httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();

    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }

}
```

**AuthorizationServer.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    public AuthorizationServerConfiguration() {

        System.out.println("AuthorizationServerConfiguration()");
    }

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("AuthorizationServerConfiguration configure()");

        //endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer()).tokenStore(tokenStore());

        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    /*@Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }*/

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("OAUTH CLIENT CONFIGURED in AuthorizationServerConfiguration !!!");

        clients.inMemory().withClient("my-trusted-client")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code",
                "refresh_token", "implicit")
        .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
        .scopes("read", "write", "trust").resourceIds("sparklr")
        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60).
        and()
        .withClient("my-client-with-registered-redirect")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code").authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
        .scopes("read", "trust").resourceIds("sparklr")
        .redirectUris("http://anywhere?key=value").
        and()
        .withClient("angular") //my-client-with-secret
        .authorizedGrantTypes("password","refresh")
        .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT").scopes("read","write").resourceIds("sparklr").accessTokenValiditySeconds(100)
        .secret("secret");
    }


}
```

**CustomTokenEnhancer.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.DefaultOAuth2AccessToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenEnhancer;

public class CustomTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {

    public CustomTokenEnhancer() {
        System.out.println("CustomTokenEnhancer()");
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {

        System.out.println("Custom Token Enhancer Initialized");

        WCSResponse wcsResponse = (WCSResponse) authentication.getPrincipal();
        authentication.getOAuth2Request().getRequestParameters();

        final Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();

        additionalInfo.put("wcsResponse", wcsResponse);

        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);

        return accessToken;
    }

}
```

Comment: How u request to rest? Can u send client code? Or access denied exception

Comment: Hi , I have two simple rest controller localhost:9080/InventoryService/inventory/sku/1100 & localhost:9080/test. These I want to secure , any client who want to access these should have access token , access token can be achieved localhost:9080/oauth/token , when I send token back I am sending cookies by using Custom token enhancer. Hope u understood what I am trying to do

Comment: My test controller & Inventory controller is similar to this one ,https://github.com/dsyer/sparklr-boot/blob/master/src/main/java/demo/Application.java

Comment: Why you want send token by cookie , i think this is not normal way in oauth , you can add token to header request, request is ajax?

Comment: I am sending oauth token as Json response and some additional stuff. I just need the configuration to secure the rest URLs. In OAuth2SecurityConfiguration.java  configure method you can see what I am trying

Comment: I dont understand whats your problem you say send cookie , i think your client request have problem

Comment: maybe your problem is in authority .remove this hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN") or add authority to client